# Website or social network to ask for a favor?

Tags: social-networks

I need to ask some people around the world to send me an image with a congratulations message for my friends who got engaged and in the image background famous landmark should appear. I can't ask on facebook pages for that because my friends will know what I am planning to do. Any suggestions where can I get help regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com)

It has a very large user base.